# oozie script unable to read date in subquery

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to fetch data whose last update date is greater that that of the existing data.

I created an oozie shell script to do so but the script failed. 
Can anyone suggest how do I accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
hive -e 'use db2;select cast(lastupdate AS BIGINT) -3 lastupdate  from table1  
      order by  lastupdate desc limit 1 ;' > date_t1.txt
wait
value=`cat date_ods1.txt`
hive --hiveconf _maxdt=$value -e "set _maxdt;set hiveconf:_maxdt;
SELECT count(*)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT* FROM tab2 WHERE code='U' AND 
      cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(eff_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd') AS BIGINT)> \${hiveconf:_maxdt} ) a;"
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute the script from command line (without oozie)?

Comment: I have tried the command in hive editor : select cast(lastupdate AS BIGINT) -3 lastupdate  from table1  
      order by  lastupdate desc limit 1 ; The query worked. on CLI i got : ParseException line 1:214 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in expression specification

Comment: I have tried the command in hive editor : select cast(lastupdate AS BIGINT) -3 lastupdate from table1 order by lastupdate desc limit 1 ; The query worked hue.But on CLI i got : ParseException line 1:214 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in expression specification

Comment: I tried shell script, it returns a blank value : oozie workflow:                               #!/bin/sh
catchData=$(beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://sda/default;principal=hive/_H.COM"  --showHeader=false --silent=true --outputformat=dsv  --verbose =false  -e "select  cast(lastupdate AS BIGINT) lastupdate from t1 order by  lastupdate desc limit 1;")
echo catchData